# 100th degree polynomial $P(2^k)=k$ for $k=0,1,...100$

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving

I sometimes see this kind of question, but I completely forgot how to solve it. Could anyone solve it for me?

[image]

Comment: See this formula for $P(x)$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577448/degrees-of-interpolating-polynomials?rq=1 The coefficient of $x^{100}$ in $l_i(x) = \prod_{0 \le k \le 100, k \ne i} \frac{x - 2^k}{2^i - 2^k}$ is  $c_i = \prod_{0 \le k \le 100, k \ne i} \frac{1}{2^i - 2^k}$. The leading coefficient of $P(x)$ is $\sum_{i=0}^{100} i c_i$. I asked Mathematica for help, and I got a number is between $-10^{-1521}$ and $-10^{1520}$. Presumably, there's another approach to the question that doesn't require something like Mathematica.

Comment: Generalize the problem in the obvious way to a degree $d$ polynomial $P_d(x)$ with $d+1$ prescribed values. Numerical experimentation indicates that the leading coefficient of $P_d(x)$ equals $(-1)^{d-1}/2^{d(d-1)/2}(2^d-1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answers. Is it possible to solve this with some problem-solving technique other than experimentation? Since I think there was such a technique, I really want to remember what it was. If there doesn't exist such stuff, i guess experimentation is the best way.